# How can I remove a numerical extension from an array of filenames?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I want to remove the last 11 characters of strings inside of an array. The array is:

```
["cool.mp3?3829483927", "wow.mp3?3872947629", "woa.mp3?8392748308"]
```

I want to convert the strings to this:

```
["cool.mp3", "wow.mp3", "woa.mp3"]
```

Is there a method specifically for this in Ruby? I know of chop and chomp, but nothing that can access each string in an array.

Comment: There are lots of ways to transform your string. What you're really missing is the #map method.

Comment: If 10 characters always follow the question mark, I think it's clearer to say you want to retain everything before the question mark. When you give an example, it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr = ["cool....]`). That way, readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them. if you read through the answers here you'll see what I mean. I realize you're new to SO, of course. Read [the SO faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help) when you have the time.

Comment: re-reading it i realize how it's sorta unclear, I'll keep what you said in mind and try not to rush it next time lol

Comment: When you reply to a comment, you want SO to notify the author of the earlier comment that a comment has been left for them. You do that by including the person's username in the comment. (I've not done that in this comment because you will be notified since it's your question. Similar with answers.) See the faq I mentioned for more information and other SO questions for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want what is before the first '?', do this :

```
arr.map{|thing| thing.split('?')[0]}
```

Comment: a little late, but I just did. All these answers are good, this one just applies to me a bit better. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

There are lots of ways to transform your string, including #slice, #split, #sub, and #partition to name a few. What you're really missing is the [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) method, which applies a method or block to each element of an array.

### Partition Your Filenames

One way to modify your array elements is to map the [Enumerable#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) method onto each element, which splits your filenames into an array of components. Ordinarily, this would return an array of arrays where each partitioned string is a sub-array, but you can have the #map block return just the components you want. In this case, what you want is the first element of each partitioned array.

This may sound complicated, but it's actually very simple. For example:

```
files = ['cool.mp3?3829483927', 'wow.mp3?3872947629', 'woa.mp3?8392748308']
files.map { |filename| filename.partition('?').first }
#=> ["cool.mp3", "wow.mp3", "woa.mp3"]
```

### A Minified Version

If you value compactness over readability, you can get the same result as the solution above with:

```
files = %w(cool.mp3?3829483927 wow.mp3?3872947629 woa.mp3?8392748308)
files.map { |f| f.partition(??)[0] }
#=> ["cool.mp3", "wow.mp3", "woa.mp3"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, all these answers just show I have alot to read tonight!

Answer (score 1):

If it's always 11 chars you can do:

```
arr=["cool.mp3?3829483927","wow.mp3?3872947629", "woa.mp3?8392748308"]
new=arr.map{|thing| thing[0...-11]}
```

Comment: can also use a regex `arr.collect {|x| x.gsub /\?.*$/, '' } ` if the 11 isn't constant, also `map` & `collect` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

[`String::slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-slice) can take a regex as an argument, so you could extract the names that you want (rather than dropping the last 11 characters):

```
arr = ["cool.mp3?3829483927","wow.mp3?3872947629", "woa.mp3?8392748308"]
arr.map! {|x| x.slice(/\w+\.mp3/) }    
#=> ["cool.mp3", "wow.mp3", "woa.mp3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `arr` is your array of strings:

```
arr.map { |s| s[/[^?]+/] }
  # => ["cool.mp3", "wow.mp3", "woa.mp3"]
```

The regular expression `/[^?]+/` matches one or more characters that are not (`^` at the beginning of the character class) question marks. This uses the methods [Array#map](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).